In Django, how to retrieve an id to use in a dynamic link?
I have a Django app. In my sidebar I have a navigation link that goes to a list of reports. That link needs an id to get the correct list of reports.
The <li> element in base.html that links to the ga_reports page is below. This link needs the app_config.id to resolve correctly. With this element {{ app_config.id }} does not exist because {{ app_config }} does not exist. I will add that on the Reports page, this link works as {{ app_config }} gets created.
Why does {{ app_config }} exist on the Reports page but not on the parent page?
                <li class="relative px-12 py-3">
                    <a class="inline-flex items-center w-full text-sm font-semibold transition-colors duration-150 hover:text-gray-800 dark:hover:text-gray-200 "
                        href="/base/ga_reports/{{ app_config.id }}">
                        <span class="ml-4">Reports</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

These are entries from base/urls.py
    path('app_config', app_config_views.app_config, name='app_config'),
    ...
    path('ga_reports/<int:app_config_id>', ga_views.ga_reports, name='ga_reports'),

The AppConfiguration model is included on base/views.py
from .models import AppConfiguration

This is base/ga_views.py
@login_required
def ga_reports(request, app_config_id):
    app_config = AppConfiguration.objects.filter(id = app_config_id).first()
    if not app_config:
        messages.error(request, "Invalid Configuration")
        return redirect('app_config')
        
    return render(request, 'base/ga_reports.html', {'app_config': app_config})

This is app_config_views.py.
@login_required
def app_config(request):
    app_configs = []
    for app_type in APP_TYPE:
        app_type_subscription = UserSubscription.objects.filter(user_id = request.user.id, app_type = app_type[0], is_active = True, is_expired = False).first()
        app_configuration = AppConfiguration.objects.filter(user_id = request.user.id, app_type = app_type[0], is_deleted = False, is_verified = True).first()
        is_subscribed = True if app_type_subscription else False #add more configurations?
        if app_configuration and is_subscribed:
            app_configuration.is_active = True
            app_configuration.save()
            print("Done")        
        is_app_configured = True if (is_subscribed and app_configuration) or (not is_subscribed) else False
        cancel_subscription_url = app_type_subscription.cancel_url if is_subscribed and app_type_subscription else ''
        
        app_configs.append({
            'app_type_k': app_type[0],
            'app_type_v': app_type[1],
            'app_type_subscription': app_type_subscription,
            'app_configuration': app_configuration,
            'is_subscribed': is_subscribed,
            'is_app_configured': is_app_configured,
            'cancel_subscription_url': cancel_subscription_url
        })

    app_config_id = 0
    content = {
        'app_config_id': app_config_id,
        'app_configs': app_configs
    }

    app_config = None
    if app_config_id != 0:
        app_config = AppConfiguration.objects.filter(id = app_config_id).first()
        if not app_config:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid Configuration")
            return redirect('app_config')

    content.update({"app_config": app_config})

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AppConfigurationForm(data=request.POST, instance=app_config)
        if form.is_valid():
            app_config = form.save(commit=False)
            app_config.user_id = request.user.id
            app_config.is_active = True
            app_config.save()
            if app_config_id != 0:
                messages.success(request, "Configuration Updated!")
            else:
                messages.success(request, "Configuration Added!")
            return redirect('app_config')

        else:
            for field_name, error_list in json.loads(form.errors.as_json()).items():
                error_message = error_list[0]["message"]
                error_message = error_message.replace('This field', f'This field ({field_name})')

                content.update({f'{field_name}_error': True})
                messages.error(request, error_message)


    return render(request, 'base/app_configurations.html', content)


As is, the block where you set an app_config object can never execute:
# app_config_views.py
# [...]
    app_config_id = 0      # <-- 1. Because of this,
    content = {
        'app_config_id': app_config_id,
        'app_configs': app_configs
    }

    app_config = None
    if app_config_id != 0: # <-- 1. (cont.) this check will always fail
                           # Which means that the below indentation never executes
        app_config = AppConfiguration.objects.filter(id = app_config_id).first()
        if not app_config:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid Configuration")
            return redirect('app_config')

    # Which means that `app_config` is `None` when the below line executes
    content.update({"app_config": app_config}) 

Your code is basically guaranteeing that app_config will never exist when the template gets rendered.

This function works correctly on the Reports page and I can see it returning the correct value. So I think this is more about the function not being available for the parent page.

That is incorrect. The reason it works on the reports page, is because you pass in app_config_id in the URL, and then use that to fetch the app_config object. On the parent page, you don't have app_config_id in the URL and you are forcibly setting app_config_id to 0 anyway - so as my answer points out, app_config is guaranteed to be nonexistent on the parent page due to your code logic.

Thank you for the detail. I rewrote that block and got it working.
